# Escape square brackets in jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, brackets

Currently I have the following `<select>` box:

```
<select name="selectemail[]" multiple="true">
    <option value="email">test@email.com</option>
    <option value="name">Joe</option>
    <option value="date">2015</option>
</select>
```

In a Javascript file I have the following:

```
$("#add").click(function(){ 
    /* Note the square brackets below */
    $("[name=selectemail[]] option:selected").each(function(){
        $("#text").val($("#text").val() + $(this).text() + "\n"); 
    });
});
```

I am trying to make it possible to transfer the content of the `<select>` box to a `<textarea>` by selecting the items that need to be transferred.

The problem is that I don't know how to escape the brackets in the name of the `<select>` box in my jQuery selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to change your selectbox slightly:

```
<select name="selectemail[]" multiple="true" id="myselect">
```

`$('#myselect')` will select the listbox but you can use this jQuery selector to grab the selected options

```
$('#myselect :selected')
```

See a **[working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sfruhcmk/)**.

If you really want to select by name you need to also escape your slashes (because they're in a string) so your selector would be:

```
$("[name=selectemail\\[\\]] :selected")
```

There are a two reasons I wouldn't do this:

1. Selecting by id is much faster than selecting by attribute (I even think selecting by class would be much faster than by name thanks to css).
2. This is horrible for readability

Comment: Yes, or $("[name='selectmail[]']")

Comment: It seems obvious that the OP could just use an ID, but that isn't what they asked how to do. This doesn't really answer the real question.

Comment: I just want to escape the brackets in the javascript code that I added: $("#add").click(function(){ 
    $("#selectemail option:selected").each(function(){ /
        $("#text").val($("#text").val() + $(this).text() + "\n"); 
    });
});

Comment: @Quartermain there are a hang of a lot of brackets in there, none of which need to be escaped (you escape brackets that are in strings) which is why I interpreted your question as I did. Which brackets, specifically are you wanting to escape and why?

Comment: I want to escape "selectemail[]" in the following line: $("#selectemail[] option:selected").each(function()

Comment: Yes. But instead of Myselect it is supposed to be selectemail[]. But I am unable to escape it. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/sfruhcmk/1/

Comment: Thank you so much! I know it is not the best way to do this but now I can build on what you have provided me. Thank you!

Comment: One more thing. How would I escape this one: var mySel = myForm.selectemail[];

Comment: @Quartermain comments are not the place for more questions and the right response would be; what have you tried? So ask on Stack Overflow and post what you've attempted. Also don't make the title "Javascript | ..." just tag it `javascript`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77624/discussion-between-quartermain-and-jcuenod).

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use backslashes to escape the brackets, like this:

```
<select name="selectemail\[\]" multiple="true">
```

Comment: I am trying to escape the brackets in the javascript code not the html code.